# Domain of Rational Functions

Tags: definition, rational-functions

I have the following definition for rational functions:

"Let $p(x), q(x)$ be polynomials and define $D=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : q(x) \neq 0 \}$

Then, the function

$$f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

is said to be rational"

My question is, if you had a proper subset A $\subset$ D and defined function:

$$g:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

Would $g$ be considered a rational function, or does the domain not being $D=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : q(x) \neq 0 \}$ mean that the function is not considered rational?

If in the above case $g$ is not considered a rational function, then if we have

$$f_1 : D_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_1(x) = \frac{p_1(x)}{q_1(x)}$$
$$D_1 = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : q_1(x) \neq 0 \}$$
and
$$f_2 : D_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_2(x) = \frac{p_2(x)}{q_2(x)}$$
$$D_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : q_2(x) \neq 0 \}$$
Is the function $\frac{f_1}{f_2}$ a rational function? What would its domain be?

Comment: This is almost not a question about mathematics, or maybe it's not precise enough? This depends heavily on context. If a book called "precalculus" talks about domains of rational functions, they mean the maximal subset of the reals where the expression is defined. But another math book might intend "rational functions" to be formal expressions in a field of fractions of a polynomial ring and not actual functions at all.

Comment: That comment was more general than your question. Since your book defines rational functions only with maximal real domain, then perhaps *in your book* you're not allowed to call it a rational function if it has a strictly smaller domain. Naming your book would help someone confirm if that's the case.

Comment: It's the lecture notes from my course at University rather than a specific book. The definition given is exactly as I've written in the original question though and the only examples of rational functions given use maximal real domain.

Comment: The reason why I actually asked this question is because it's stated in the notes (without proof) that the set of rational functions is closed under composition, and I was trying to prove this myself but ran into problems due to this issue with the domains of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\subset\Bbb R$ and $p(x),q(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ are such that $(\forall y\in A):q(y)\ne0$, then $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is a rational function. And a rational function (whose domain is a subset of $\Bbb R$) is any function which can be defined this way.

Comment: So the domain of a rational function can be ANY subset of the set of real numbers such that the denominator of the function is nonzero?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.